# Django ModelChoiceField not being updated with new data

Tags: django, django-forms

Using Django 1.7, I have a `ModelChoiceField` that does not get updated when the underlying data is updated. To have the new data row show up, I need to restart the web server.

**Django Form, Field, View:**

```
class JobsModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobsModelChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        groups = groupby(sorted(kwargs['queryset'], key=attrgetter('company')), attrgetter('company'))
        self.choices = [(company, [(t.id, self.label_from_instance(t)) for t in title])
                        for company, title in groups]

    def label_from_instance(self, job):
        return u'{} {}'.format(job.id, job.title)

class NewApplicationForm(forms.Form):
    id = JobsModelChoiceField(queryset=Job.objects.all(),
                                widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'chosen-select'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    phone_number = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number', max_length=42, required=False)
    resume = forms.FileField()

    def save(self):
        # save data

class NewApplicationView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):

    template_name = 'applicants/new_application.html'
    form_class = NewApplicationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('applicants:add')
    success_message = "Job Application was created successfully"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.save()
        return super(NewApplicationView, self).form_valid(form)
```

An example of the problem I get is that if I add a new row into the jobs table, that new row isn't displayed in the form choice field until I restart the web server.

Answer (score 7):

This is beacuse the field of your form is populated statically, not dynamically (i.e. not every time your form is instantiated). You should specify the form queryset in the form `__init__` method, as follows:

```
class NewApplicationForm(forms.Form):
    id = JobsModelChoiceField(queryset=Job.objects.none(), ...)

...


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['id'].queryset = Job.objects.all()
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why this answer has been downvoted without a comment ... :-?

Comment: this is correct answer, it's work for me  and i upvote, thank you!